# how to get the result of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my Javascript

```
              <script type="text/javascript">


                window.onload=function(){

            /* This showResult function is used as the callback function*/

            function showResult(result) {
                document.getElementById('latitude').value = result.geometry.location.lat();
                document.getElementById('longitude').value = result.geometry.location.lng();
            }

            function getLatitudeLongitude(callback, address) {
                // If adress is not supplied, use default value 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain'
                address = address || 'Ferrol, Galicia, Spain';
                // Initialize the Geocoder
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                if (geocoder) {
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'address': address
                    }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            callback(results[0]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            var button = document.getElementById('btn');

            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                getLatitudeLongitude(showResult, address)
            });

                }

            </script>
```

Here is my html code

```
            <input id="address" type="text" size="50" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Изберете локация" autocomplete="on">

                <button  id="btn" name="get" value="get">get</button>
                <div>


            The result of latidude and longitude id to be added as value

                    <p>Latitude:
                        <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" readonly />
                    </p>
                    <p>Longitude:
                        <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" readonly />
                    </p>
```

The result show by id on input but i can't get with variable

How to get the result of document.getElementById **latitude** and **longitude** and turn into php variable to use for mysql insert

Comment: You can't turn something you have in JS into a PHP variable, you have to somehow pass it to the server

Comment: Yes, Luca is right, you'll have to consider either a page reload or an ajax call.

Comment: Use $(document).ready(function(){ instead of window.onload=function(){

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function below might help you send `POST` request to `save_coordinates.php` file on server to save coordinate values i.e, `latitude` and `longitude` in database.

```
function saveLatLong(latitude, longitude){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("POST", "save_coordinates.php", true);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhttp.send("latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude);
   return true;
}
```